# remove special characters from a file in linux

Tags: linux

I am trying to remove a bunch of ^K from a file in linux for class but everything I have been trying is not working.

so I cat a file memo.txt and it has double spaced lines

I less the file and it has ^K after every line

I am trying to remove the ^K and output it into a new file

I have tried

```
cat memo.txt | tr -d "\n" > memo.new
cat memo.txt | tr -d "^K" > memo.new
```

and some other sed functions.

Comment: Every character is special in its own way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to try something like this:

```
tr -d '\013' < memo.txt > memo.new
```

`013` is the octal value for the character `^K`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and not just some man page. I know this is for school but I tried.

Comment: You can also get the value by pressing Ctrl+v followed by Ctrl+K. Ctrl+v makes the next input give it's literal value instead of having its normal effect

Comment: @Jonathan Callen, how did u find octal value of ^K?

Comment: `^A` through `^Z` are the characters numbered 1-26; `K` is the 11th letter, so a simple base conversion gives `013` octal.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at:

```
man strings
```

that's imho exactly what you want...

Comment: You feel the need to potentially destroy the content just to remove a single character completely?

Answer (score 0):

I think ABCD's answer will work.  But if it doesn't work, try the following:

```
tr -d "`echo -e '\013'`" < memo.txt > memo.new
```

The embedded echo command will output the actual ^K character, so tr will know *exactly* what to delete.